# Error while parsing xslt string to dom

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

We are trying this in ie11 and we are getting syntax error .

```
function transformToHtmlText(xmlFormId, xsltFormId) {

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById(xmlFormId).innerHTML, "application/xml");
    //Below line throwing Syntax Error
    var xsltDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById(xsltFormId).innerHTML, "application/xml");
    //var htmlContent = xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
        var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
        var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
        xslDoc.loadXML((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xsltDoc));
        xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
        var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
        xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
        xslProc.transform();
        return xslProc.output;
    //return htmlContent;
}
```

XML is :

```
<form FormID="63" FormTableName="xx_resolution" IssueName="XX Resolution">
    <is_trainable required="Y" state="Req"></is_trainable>
    <Follow_Up_Req required="Y" state="Req"></Follow_Up_Req>
    <Follow_Up_Date></Follow_Up_Date>
    <Refer_Out_Req required="Y" state="Req"></Refer_Out_Req>
    <Refer_To></Refer_To>
    <Refer_To_Name></Refer_To_Name>
    <Refer_To_TN TNType="xxx-xxx-xxxx"></Refer_To_TN>
    <Action_history_list NameList="Y" style="Section"></Action_history_list>
    <Action_Date></Action_Date>
    <Action_User></Action_User>
    <Action_summary></Action_summary>
    <Call_Category></Call_Category>
    <Call_Category_1_></Call_Category_1_>
    <Call_Category_2_></Call_Category_2_>
    <Call_Category_3_></Call_Category_3_>
    <Call_Category_4_></Call_Category_4_>
    <Call_Category_5_></Call_Category_5_>
    <Add_Cat></Add_Cat>
    <CA_ID></CA_ID>
    <CA_SUP_ID></CA_SUP_ID>
    <CA_CENTER_ID></CA_CENTER_ID>
</form>
```

and the XSLT that we are using is :

```
<div xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<xsl:for-each select="Action_history_list/row">
    <span style="width: 32px;"></span>
    <span class="copy" style="width: 81px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="_Action_User"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 7px;"></span>
    <span class="copy" style="width: 181px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="_Action_Date"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 11px;"></span>
    <span class="copy" style="width: 95px;">
        <span class="label" id="Action_summary_label_row_">Action summary</span>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 9px;"></span>
    <span class="copy" style="width: 197px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="_Action_summary"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>
    <br>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

as per our understanding even though the tag is empty, at least empty span should be displayed . But we are getting error in the line we mentioned in the comment.

Please help.

Comment: Don't try to put XML into an HTML document and then expect to be able to parse it as XML with DOMParser being fed some innerHTML. HTML and XML have a different syntax. Also note that the XSLT namespace is `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`.

Comment: There's an unclosed `<br>` element in your XSLT, meaning that your XSLT is not valid XML. What happens if you change that to `<br />`?

Comment: @JLRishe  we will try and update you on this.. thanks for pointing it out.